# Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default

Tags: drupal-8

Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use `\Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse` for it.

I am getting this error while enabling my custom module in **Drupal 8**.

Answer (score 0):

Check you `routing.yml` and `menu.yml`
Your rout name that you have created should be there in `menu.yml` like:

***In routing.yml***

```
test_module.description:
  path: 'testing/new-example'
  defaults:
    _controller:  '\Drupal\test_module\Controller\Page::description'
    _title: 'Form API Examples'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

***and in menu.yml***

```
test_module.description:
  title: Form API Examples
  description: Form examples using Drupal Form API.
  route_name: test_module.description
```